# uml class diagram association to super class or all the child classes

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Given that there is a super class along two sub classes that inherit that super class.

If both the sub classes are having association with the same class, do we must put an association to the super class or may we put association for each sub class in certain situation?

For example,
[image]
would it be suitable to put "uses" association to both Child and Adult just like above since Child and Adult use LegoSet in different way? Or instead, should I only put the association between Person and LegoSet?

Comment: The use you're describing is as an argument to methods on the subclasses; if these were overloads of methods on the base-class, I'd say attach to `Person`.  Since they're not, it seems more appropriate to attach them to the subclasses.  This is largely opinion.  As an aside, one might expect `HouseLegoSet` and `DragonLegoSet` to be derived from `LegoSet`, so that you can use type safety to ensure that a dragon-themed `LegoSet` is not passed to `Child`'s `buildHouse` method.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with lockcmpxhg8b, since you've got to separate operations defined that take a LegoSet the associations are probably at the subclass level here. However, there is a 'design smell' emanating from this; I'd want myself to look at how the Build() operation can be abstracted up and defined at the Person level. Like lockcmpxchg8b says sub-typing your LegoSet would be a way to do it. You could also define a IBuildable interface perhaps that LegoSet implements. Something like "+Build (set: IBuildable) : void" with base abstract Impl. Also Person is prob. not composed of LegoStructure?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Post that as answer, please.

Comment: I hesitate to formally answer anything opinion based.  The question should probably technically be closed on those grounds.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I don't think it's opinion based and so far nobody else too. Even if it will be closed your comment is an (worth) an answer.